# Remove first (if C) and last letter if (F or W)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove the **first letter if it is a C** and the **last letter if it is a F or a W**.
But when I use :

```
df1['trimmed_seq'] = df1['seq'].str.strip("CFW")
```

Input:

```
    seq
0   CASSAQGTGDRGYTF
1   CASSLVATGNTGELFF
2   CASSKGTVSGLSG
3   CALKVGADTQYF
4   CASSLWASGRGGTGELFF
5   CASSLLGWEQLDEQFF
6   CASSSGTGVYGYTF
7   CASSPLEWEGVTEAFF
8   CASSFWSSGRGGTDTQYF
9   CASSAGQGASDEQFF
```

Output:

```
    seq
0   ASSAQGTGDRGYT
1   ASSLVATGNTGEL
2   ASSKGTVSGLSG
3   ALKVGADTQY
4   ASSLWASGRGGTGEL
5   ASSLLGWEQLDEQ
6   ASSSGTGVYGYT
7   ASSPLEWEGVTEA
8   ASSFWSSGRGGTDTQY
9   ASSAGQGASDEQ
```

The problem I have is that for example for line '1' both F's at the end are removed and in case a sequence would end with CFW all this would be removed.

So my question is: can this be solved somehow using the same str.strip function?

Comment: `strip` does not take an optional argument that limits the number of characters stripped, so it seems impossible to achieve what you want using `strip`, at least directly (you can use `strip` indirectly to test if the conditions are met, but that would be ugly). Why not just use `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` operations to filter out the required rows and `.str` to perform the string formatting

```
mask = (df.seq.str[0] == 'C') 
df.loc[mask, "seq"] = df.loc[mask, "seq"].str[1:]

mask = (df.seq.str[-1] == 'F') | (df.seq.str[-1] == 'W') 
df.loc[mask, "seq"] = df.loc[mask, "seq"].str[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using strip because it has no notion of a maximum number of characters to remove. So I would use replace and an regex to remove an optional prefix and an optional suffix:

```
df['seq'].str.replace(r'^C?(.*?)[FW]?$', r'\1')
```

It gives as expected:

```
0       ASSAQGTGDRGYT
1      ASSLVATGNTGELF
2        ASSKGTVSGLSG
3          ALKVGADTQY
4    ASSLWASGRGGTGELF
5      ASSLLGWEQLDEQF
6        ASSSGTGVYGYT
7      ASSPLEWEGVTEAF
8    ASSFWSSGRGGTDTQY
9       ASSAGQGASDEQF
Name: seq, dtype: object
```